# Can we get the other people information with our ACCESS_TOKEN

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

I'm trying to use this API,

> https://people.googleapis.com/v1/{resourceName=people/*}

here if I use mine i.e., people/me for **resourceName** and addresses for **personFields** I'm getting the results.

But I need to check the other people details in our organisation, is there any way to get.

With the same api , I think need to pass the resource name people/{user_id}, ow can we get the other people user_id to make request?

Thanks

Comment: any suggestion on this.

Answer (score 0):

Google people api [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get) is a public method which means it accesses public data.

Assuming you have the persons user id you can request their data using an api key from the Google developer console.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/108822296317431956650?key=XXXX
```

the trick will be finding their user id.  The only way i know if is finding them on Google+

Comment: Ya, actually I stuck at to get the user_ID,  Can you suggest me a bit more to find them(user ID) in google+.

I gone through search api of People to get the results there also I didn't find the user_Id

Comment: I tried this, after login I gone through [https://plus.google.com/people] where I saw all people and there I find the individual userID.

This I'm finding manuallu but any API to get the people and their userIDS?

One more, [https://plus.google.com/people], once I reloaed I able to see all the people's userids and designation in network response. But any API to get the people and their userids?

Comment: There is no endpoint for searching on a users name or email address you have to know their id to get their information.

Comment: @DalmTo, without this id(userid/profileid) I can't get the other people department details, but how can I get the id.

what I'm trying to achieve is, I need to get the other people profile details in my organisation like need to retrieve their PhoneNumber, address, Manager details etc., I'm able to see in ui it filled up. Looking for this type API.

Comment: search for them on Google+ is the only way i know of.  As in the social media website you will have to do it manually

Comment: @DalmTo, I saw some details with their contact details, [https://contacts.google.com/other] from contacts is there a way to get the profile details like address, Phone number, Manager etc

Comment: google contacts is a different system its like an address book and requires that the owner of the address book fill out the information.   It does not necessarily link to address book entire google account and you can not garentee that the owner of the address book has added the information for the user you are looking for